# Controller buttons do what?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I'm building a website that will be accessed from game console browsers. However, I'm struggling to find information about what a given controller's buttons do. I'm really only concerned with PS4 and Xbox One. The only resources I've come across are the following:

- [Article with links to the following](http://blog.greggant.com/posts/2016/04/07/exploring-and-developing-for-the-ps4-browser.html)

  - [PS4 Internet Browser](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/Internet_Browser)

    - [Web Content Guidelines for PS4](http://www.sie.com/content/dam/corporate/jp/guideline/PS4_Web_Content-Guidelines_e.pdf)
- [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API)
- [Using the... to Add Controller Support to Browser Games](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-html5-gamepad-api-to-add-controller-support-to-browser-games--cms-21345)

None of these seem to explain what a controller's buttons do or to what actions they correspond to. Any information or help would be greatly appreciated.

Is there any way to test this sort of thing without an actual video game console or controllers?

Comment: The buttons don't inherently 'do' anything; there's merely 'keys' that the user can press. It's up to you to decide what to do with them. Consider them to be the equivalent of [**keyCodes**](http://keycode.info/) in JavaScript. Mozilla has a [**great tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) branching from the page you linked :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge At a minimum he needs to know what each button's keycode is.

Comment: They don't have a corresponding keycode; I was meaning that they behave *like* keycodes -- you receive them as a direct input, and craft logic based on which combinations of inputs are entered.

Comment: MDN docs pretty much say everything needed to get started. Please narrow the focus of the question to a more specific issue.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yeah i'm currently reading another article about the [HTML5 Gamepad API](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-html5-gamepad-api-to-add-controller-support-to-browser-games--cms-21345), but I don't believe it's even supported by PS4 since PS4 supports very little HTML5.

Comment: @ObsidianAge How then can you make the controls consistent from session to session if the input you receive has no defining characteristics??

Comment: They do have defining characteristics. You can use `var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[e.gamepad.index]` and then access the buttons via `gp.index` and `gp.id`. The basics are covered in the tutorial I linked earlier. For specifics, I'm afraid you'll need to define your question further.

Comment: @ObsidianAge is there any way to simulate that environment and test this stuff without a game console or controller?

Comment: I can't think of any easy way of doing that, but there's probably a plugin somewhere. However, gamepads are fairly cheap, and can be connected simply via USB. You can test the **logic** of your game without one; simply bypass the gamepad requirement. For example, when making a character move left, you would check that the left arrow is pressed, rather than the gamepad controller's thumbstick.

Comment: @ObsidianAge we are talking about controllers (like Xbox One) and not pads (like you'd find on an arcade game), right? Yes, i know i can test the logic without one. So do the arrow keys correspond to the analog joysticks? I do have an Xbox 360 controller, but would the Gamepad index vary from, say, an Xbox 360 controller to an Xbox One controller?

Comment: They don't *correspond* to the keys at all. They are completely **independent** forms of input that you need to validate against. [**navigator.getGamepads()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getGamepads) returns the thumsticks as **objects**, from which you can work out the way in which the thumbstick is being moved with `navigator.getGamepads()[0].axes`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge k thanks!